# display each data on a form using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and exploring it. I'm having a hard time doing this. So far this is what I have tried.

**Controller.php**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Customer_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('customer_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Customer';
        $data['records'] = $this->customer_model->getAll();
        $data['groups'] = $this->customer_model->getAllCustomerGroups();
        $data['groupcodes'] = $this->customer_model->getAllCustomerGroups();
        $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/navbar',$data);
        $this->load->view('customer_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('include/sidebar',$data);
        $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);

    }
}
```

**Model.php**

```
 function getAll() {
            $query = $this->db->get('customercard');
            return $query->row_array();       
        }
```

**View.php**

```
              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCustomerCode3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCustomerCode3" readonly>
            </div>

            <label for="inputWebsite3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Website</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="url" class="form-control" id="inputWebsite3" placeholder="Website">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCustomerName3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCustomerName3" placeholder="Customer Name">
            </div>

            <label for="inputContact3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputContact3" placeholder="Contact">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCustomerGroup3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Group</label>


            <label for="inputIncomeAccount3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Income Account</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputIncomeAccount3" placeholder="Income Account">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCustomerType3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCustomerType3" placeholder="Customer Type">
            </div>
            <label for="inputSalesPerson3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Sales Person</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSalesPerson3" placeholder="Sales Person">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCustomerAddress3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCustomerAddress3" placeholder="Customer Address">
            </div>

            <label for="inputCreditLimit3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Credit Limit</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCreditLimit3" placeholder="Credit Limit">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputCustomerAddressAlt3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">AddressAlt</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCustomerAddressAlt3" placeholder="Customer AddressAlt">
            </div>

            <label for="inputTin3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tin</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTin3" placeholder="Tin">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPhone13" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone1</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone13" placeholder="Phone1">
            </div>

            <label for="inputTaxCode3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tax Code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTaxCode3" placeholder="Tax Code">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPhone23" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone2</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPhone23" placeholder="Phone2">
            </div>

            <label for="inputTerms3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Terms</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTerms3" placeholder="Terms">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputFax3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fax</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFax3" placeholder="Fax">
            </div>

            <label for="inputPriceCode3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price Code</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPriceCode3" placeholder="Price Code">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> 
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>  
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span> 
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

What I want to do is to display the data from the database to my form. I chose

```
  $query = $this->db->get('customercard');
```

which produces

```
  SELECT * FROM customercard
```

But I want to display each record on the form, and then as you notice I have navigation buttons, first, previous, next and last. I want to loop through the record using these buttons. I don't know how to display it in view. So I ask that you give me some tutorials to get started with or help me with the code so I could continue what I'm doing. Help is truly appreciated. Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change model to

```
function getAll() {
            $query = $this->db->get('customercard');
            return $query->result_array();       
        }
```

Also note that when you pass `$data['records']` to the view, you can access it by simply `$records` from your view.

In your view, just loop through it.

```
<?php
foreach ($recordsas $value)
  {
  echo "$value <br>";
  }
?>
```

-----------You can try the below.
It's a simple method of getting the next record according to your needs.

MODEL

```
public function fetch_customers($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->select('customercode,customername,customergroup,customertype,customeraddress,website');
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $this->db->where('customercode >',$start);
    $this->db->order_by('customercode');
    $query = $this->db->get('customercard');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row();
        $data[] = $row;
        return $data;
    } else {
        return false;
     }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function index(){
    $shown_id = 0;
    if(isset($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $shown_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }
    $this->load->model('customers_model');
    $data['info'] = $this->customers_model->fetch_customers(1,$shown_id);
    $this->load->view('customer_info',$data);
}
```

VIEW

```
$customer_id = $info->customercode;
$customer_name = $info->customername;
//Use like above to get the customer info and show as you like
```

BUT, when you make the "next" button, you need to pass along the $customer_id back to the controller.
You can have an hyperlink do this too.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>controller_name/index/<?php echo $customer_id;?>"
```

Or use a button with `onclick` and `window.location`

Comment: I have two records, it's displaying the two records but I want one row at a time then when I click the next button then go to the next record.

Comment: Then you will either need to use ajax to show the next record in the same page, or use post to get the next request. You can simply hide the current rows id in a hidden variable and get the next 1 row. You will have to use LIMIT in your model's function

Comment: I don't mean to come out harsh but I can't write a bunch of code for you. I can point you the direction on how to write it though and then help you along the way.

Comment: Basically you will need to make sure that you retrieve only one record and keep a record on which record you previously pulled. Once you have that, the next time you want to grab information you can simply get the next one by using ORDER BY in your SQL and add the the WHERE to be greater than the previously selected record. This will involve you interacting with the controller, model and view. You will have to pass on the last selected to record to the controller and in turn to the model and get the data from the model and send it to your view. If you can have some code done, we can help you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41150/discussion-between-neknek-mouh-and-ela-buwa)

Comment: you might want to check this <http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/>. Works in same way that you want your piece of code to work.